# getting error responses from nft.storage's /store API endpoint using fetch

Tags: fetch, ipfs

```
      let formData  = new FormData();

      formData.append("name",name);
      formData.append("description",description);
      formData.append("image", image);

      fetch("https://api.nft.storage/store",{
        method: "POST",
        body: formData, 
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer '+process.env.TEST_API_KEY,
        }
      }).then(response => response.json())
      .then((json)=>{
        console.log(json)
      })
```

This is what I've been trying to do but keep getting error as a response. Errors are usually invalid-file or something to do with content-type.
https://nft.storage/api-docs/ - This is the api documentation. If theres any example for the same, it'll be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Long time since question... just for any one wondering:

The api endpoint receives 1 parameter called meta which is a json_encoded representation of the fields, any falsy value like image: undefined, will be replaced with an extra field you must include, with the binary representation of the field... here is an example:

```
let params = {
  name: 'name of the nft',
  image: undefined,
  description: 'description of the nft'
}  
let formData  = new FormData();
formData.append("meta",JSON.stringify(params));
formData.append("image",new File([ someBinaryImageData ], 'nft.png', { type: 'image/png' });

fetch("https://api.nft.storage/store",{
  method: "POST",
  body: formData, 
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+process.env.TEST_API_KEY,
  }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then((json)=>{
    console.log(json);
})
```